# Deploy Symfony 3 project

Tags: php, symfony, ovh

I'm just create my application using symfony 3 with database (mysql) in localhost
and I have domainName So how to configure my database and to configure the default route(because in localhost I configured my website with nameproject/web/app_dev.php

thank you

Comment: You want to know how to deploy an entire Symfony application. That's a way too big task to describe on StackOverflow. You should start with the official tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've configured your webserver to use `app_dev.php` as the default `IndexFile`. Use `app.php` instead and you should be on your way.

If you use different database settings on you dev and live environments, you should be able to set those in your `/app/config/parameters.yml` file.

Comment: I need to know steps to deploy Symfony 3 project